# validate not empty field within table javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

Compare Empty fields among textboxes and dropdowns

Comment: Selected how exactly, a select elements default value is the text in the first option ?

Answer (score 0):

Set a default value for all of them.
Then just check if their value = the default.
Until they select something else, they will remain default.